Why my Cyrillic text is not rendered in T2A and UTF-8?
I'm doing this (I need the \ttfamily):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\begin{document}
\ttfamily тест
\end{document}

The тест text is not rendered correctly, even though I see no compilation errors or even warnings (I use pdflatex and don't want to switch to anything else). I see this:


\documentclass{article} \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} \begin{document} \ttfamily тест \end{document} works correctly. @egreg is very fast. :-) After: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is default since 2018.

A few years ago, the LaTeX team decided it was time to make UTF-8 the default encoding when reading a document.
In retrospect, the decision has been good: modern text editors save files as UTF-8, unless specifically instructed not to.
However, this opened a problem: there might be legacy documents that were written using features depending on strict 8 bit interpretation (the number should be very small), so in order to cope with this case, a user can simply declare
\UseRawInputEncoding

at the beginning of their file.
I can think to a few other situations where the command might be used. Yours isn't.
You're explicitly declaring that LaTeX should ignore UTF-8 and interpret byte-by-byte. Indeed, you get eight characters instead of four, because Cyrillic characters are two-byte in UTF-8.
Even without trying, I state that
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily тест
\end{document}

will produce the expected output. Of course you should also load babel with the appropriate language choice.
Historical note
The examples I refer to were documents encoded, say, in Latin-1, which had something like
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`é=\active
\def é{\'e}

\begin{document}

é

\end{document}

which would fail with UTF-8 interpretation. They won't if \UseRawInputEncoding is stated at the very beginning. But newer document should be UTF-8 encoded and rely on the standard features that already cope with the most common accented letters.
